# Set "badge" count for iOS app using Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to set badge count through FMC but it seems like "badge" property of Message is ignored, because when the notification is delivered badge count of the app is different than one from "apns"

Example
I define "badge" as 42 so I expect 42 as badge count when a notification is delivered but I get 1 (if there is no previous notifications)

I'm using Firebase Cloud functions with FCM to send notifications

```
admin.messaging().send(message)
```

here is example of message

```
{
    "notification": {
        "body": "TEST"
    },
    "apns": {
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "threadId": "...",
                "badge": 42,
                "mutableContent": true
            }
        },
        "headers": {
            "apns-collapse-id": "..."
        }
    },
    "token": "...",
    "data": {
        "collapseID": "...",
        "jsonData": "...",
        "fcmToken": "..."
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to set the number on the red badge, you must use `notification_count` instead of `badge`

Comment: @saperlipopette thanks for comment sorry I can't verify your answer cuz I have used other approach to resolve my problem, thanks for your time and have a nice day

Comment: hey @PhilipDolenko can you share your approach please

Comment: Sorry @mazen it was 2 years ago so I just forgot ;) BTW There is a war in my country now  so I cant really spent  time on StackOverflow, hope someone else will help you with your problem

Comment: stay safe @PhilipDolenko

Comment: @mazen this worked for me 
`const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "You have new notifications", // Title for the notification
        body: "Check them out!", // Body for the notification
      },
      apns: {
        payload: {
          aps: {
            badge: unreadCount,
          },
        },
      },
      token: notificationToken,
    };`